# How to validate Signed PDF file

Tags: docusignapi

I want to verify Docusign signed PDF using java code. I need to verify PDF is not modified after signing and it is signed by proper user. How to do that?

Following is the code I used to verify it using JSignPdf library. This was working till this March 7th but failing now. Not getting what is the issue. Please guide me if there is any changes in Docusign signature certificate in signed PDF.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import net.sf.jsignpdf.verify.SignatureVerification;
import net.sf.jsignpdf.verify.VerificationResult;
import net.sf.jsignpdf.verify.VerifierLogic;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.vit.common.signing.VerificationOutput;
public class PdfVerifier{
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PdfVerifier.class);    
    public VerificationOutput verify(String signedFileName) throws Exception {        
        return verify(signedFileName, null);
    }
    public VerificationOutput verify(String pdfFileName, String[] certFileNames) throws Exception {
        VerificationOutput ret = new VerificationOutput();
        logger.info("starting checking ... " + pdfFileName);
        try {
            boolean failFast = true;
            final VerifierLogic tmpLogic = new VerifierLogic("", "", "");
            tmpLogic.setFailFast(failFast);
            if (certFileNames==null || certFileNames.length==0) {
                //TODO: we may just do this once per jvm launching
                ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
                InputStream ins = null; 
                try {
                    ins = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("docusign.cer");
                    tmpLogic.addX509CertFile(ins);
                    ins = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("docusign_entrust.cer");
                    tmpLogic.addX509CertFile(ins);
                }  finally {
                    try {
                        if (ins!=null) ins.close();
                    } catch(Exception err) {}
                }
            } else {
                for (String tmpCFile : certFileNames) {
                    tmpLogic.addX509CertFile(tmpCFile);
                }
            }
            int exitCode = 0;
            String tmpFilePath = pdfFileName;
            int exitCodeForFile = 0;
            logger.info("Verifying " + tmpFilePath);
            final File tmpFile = new File(tmpFilePath);
            if (!tmpFile.canRead()) {
                exitCodeForFile = SignatureVerification.SIG_STAT_CODE_ERROR_FILE_NOT_READABLE;
                logger.error("Couln't read the file " + tmpFile + ". Check the path and permissions.");
                exitCode = Math.max(exitCode, exitCodeForFile);
                ret.setPass(false);
                ret.setMessage("Couln't read the file " + tmpFile);
            }
            final VerificationResult tmpResult = tmpLogic.verify(tmpFilePath, null);
            if (tmpResult.getException() != null) {
                Exception e = tmpResult.getException();
                exitCodeForFile = SignatureVerification.SIG_STAT_CODE_ERROR_UNEXPECTED_PROBLEM;
                exitCode = Math.max(exitCode, exitCodeForFile);
                ret.setPass(false);
                ret.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                ret.setException(e);
                logger.error("failed digital signature verification due to " + e.getMessage(), e);
            } else {
                logger.info("Total revisions: " + tmpResult.getTotalRevisions());
                exitCodeForFile = tmpResult.getVerificationResultCode();
                boolean modified = false;
                boolean signatureVerified = false;
                for (SignatureVerification verification: tmpResult.getVerifications()) {
                    if (verification.isModified()) modified = true;
                    if (verification.getFails()==null) {
                        signatureVerified = true;
                        //System.out.println(verification.getSubject());
                        String subject = verification.getSubject();
                        String[] firstSplit = subject.split(",");
                        String email = firstSplit[0].substring(4, firstSplit[0].length()-1);
                        //System.out.println(email);
                        ret.setSignerEmail(email);
                    } else if (verification.isSignCertTrustedAndValid()) {
                        signatureVerified = true;
                    }
                }
                if (modified) {
                    ret.setPass(false);
                    ret.setMessage("pdf has been modified");
                } else {
                    if (signatureVerified) {
                        ret.setPass(true);
                        ret.setMessage("Both content and signing cert have been verified");
                    } else {
                        ret.setPass(false);
                        ret.setMessage("signature not verified");
                    }
                }
                logger.info("verification passed? " + ret.isPass());
                if (!ret.isPass()) {
                    logger.info("reason failed is " + ret.getMessage());
                }
            }
            exitCode = Math.max(exitCode, exitCodeForFile);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very vague, can you please provide a more detailed question ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. We have a customer service application. This application creates a docusign envelope for each customer requests. Customers need to fill this envelope and sign to place the order. Once envelope is signed by custemers our server downloads it's Signed PDF, parse signed PDF and  process the client request. But before process the client request we want to check this signed PDF is not tampered/modified by anyone else.

Comment: I'm not sure that you're in the right section as your question is not specific to DocuSign but more to your own application as you will need to implement the "PDF Check" within your application. What programming language are you using for your application ?

Comment: We are using JSignPdf. It is a free open source library used to verify signature of PDF files. It was working till March 7th, but now it is failing by showing following error
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.BERTaggedObject cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERTaggedObject
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(Unknown Source)
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature

This validation code was working for past few years. But now it is failing. Not getting what is the issue.

Comment: I posted code I am using for reference.

Comment: Looks like to fix this issue I need to use latest jar file. In bcprov-jdk15.1.46.jar file BERTaggedObject  is a child class of  DERTaggedObject but not in the current jar file bcprov-jdk15on.1.49.jar